# Does anyone know what is growing in my sweet pea soil?

Tags: identification, plant-health

I am trying to grow my first deck garden (all in pots on my balcony). I am trying to grow sweet peas that I started from seeds that I left in a damp paper towel in a plastic bag for about a week before transferring them into the dirt. They have been planted in dirt for about two weeks and I just noticed this odd dark yellowish substance appearing on the dirt surface and around the plant roots.

Does anyone know what this is? Is it harmful?

[image: growing in the soil]

Comment: Two weeks later, do you have any news for us? Did the stuff grow further? Can you add another picture into your question?